# Possibilites in writing in LDAP using Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, ldap

Is it possible to change attributes of a user in LDAP via django?

As of now, I can't find any solution on the Internet.

I have the **django-auth-ldap** backend and I can log in as a user (GUI). But I can't change any of their attributes, i.e. I can't change the name.

What do I have to write or extend? If you have any idea let me know.

Do I have to write in my views, models, forms or whatever?

Comment: Since django-auth-ldap uses python-ldap have you tried looking at this in the documention: [modifyModList](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap-modlist.html#ldap.modlist.modifyModlist)

Comment: yes but I don't think that this can help me. I just want to change first_name and last_name of a user. And also the password on a "password reset"-page

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand but the modifyModList is going to give you the LDIF that you need to run through the modify (or modify_s) which will change the attributes you are looking for.